# What kind of power supply is best for IoT application?

Tags: power-supply, transformerless

I am trying to make some IoT devices to fit in wall outlet. There is an issue with power supply. I have to feed my circuits from 220V outlet and there is a limitation in size.
I tried to use some HLK modules, but those are big and expensive.
I think IoT devices use some kind of transformerless power supplies (am I right?) but I have voltage drop problem with them.
What kind of power supply is recommended to power my 5V/500mA circuits from 200V AC?

(My English is poor so please excuse me for my bad grammar!)

Comment: *some kind of transformerless power supplies* Then those will be **non isolated** meaning that the complete circuit will be at **mains live voltage** that means safety measures have to be taken. If you have no clue about this then don't use a transformer less power supply. Dealing with 220V is for educated engineers only! How about making a device that uses a 5 V USB socket, then you can simply use a phone charger and everything should be safe.

Comment: The whole circuit is mounted in the wall and I can't use chargers. And it is sealed so there should be no shock hazards. Could you please give me an example of those "some kind of transformerless power supplies"? :)

Comment: This is a very vague question. I think you're thinking of a switch mode power supply when you refer to some kind of "transformerless power supplies". I agree with @Bimpelrekkie you shouldn't be playing around with mains power unless you're an expert.

Comment: *The whole circuit is mounted in the wall* Then reliability, safety and robustness is even more important. What if some component fails and catches fire? A ready made module that is designed to be permanently connected to mains voltage would be the best choice. It is not something you can design as a beginner, so don't. You are **asking for trouble** if you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I think IoT devices use some kind of transformerless power supplies
>   (am I right?) but I have voltage drop problem with them.*

\$\color{red}{\text{THIS IS A DANGEROUS (and actually pointless) UNDERTAKING}}\$

To make a transformerless power supply capable of delivering 500 mA at 5 volts is fraught with problems. Even if your supply stayed steady at 220 volts AC at (say) 50 Hz, the only feasible technology is to use a dropper capacitor. This would then feed a bridge rectifier and zener diode followed by a a DC smoothing circuit.

However, the dropper capacitor required to be able to deliver 500 mA at the load is going to be about 15 uF: -

[image]

I've shown a 250 volt AC rated capacitor to give it sufficient headroom in case of over-voltage situations but, this is by no-means a suitable solution because if the capacitor fails you would also need a fuse. This area of the design is crucial AND the only suitable capacitor I can find is this one: -

[image]

It's probably going to be about twice the size of a small flyback transformer. Anyway, here's the graph of the output voltage over time: -

[image]

So it's producing 5 (ish) volts when the load is 10 ohms (500 mA). But look how big the output capacitor needs to be: 10,000 uF and will probably have a voltage rating of 6.3 volts: -

[image]

---

### Conclusion

\$\color{red}{\text{It's an utterly pointless and dangerous undertaking - use a small flyback converter}}\$

> *What kind of power supply is recommended to power my 5V/500mA circuits*

Use a safe and reliable flyback converter.